# Integrating Google Login Button on web app fails at verifyIdToken() step

Tags: php, google-identity

I am trying to integrate with Google Identity Services using the Google login button on a web app built with PHP. I am able to get the button to show and even receive the post with the token. But when trying to validate the token a call seems to be made to retrieve certs from Google but this appears to fail. Please help

```
[Wed Mar 15 12:29:59.074744 2023] [php:error] [pid 71] [client 172.17.0.1:43470] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException: Unable to read from stream in /var/www/html/vendor/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/Stream.php:237
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/Utils.php(53): GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Stream->read()
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/StreamHandler.php(210): GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Utils::copyToStream()

#13 /var/www/html/vendor/google/apiclient/src/AccessToken/Verify.php(173): GuzzleHttp\\Client->get()
#14 /var/www/html/vendor/google/apiclient/src/AccessToken/Verify.php(201): Google\\AccessToken\\Verify->retrieveCertsFromLocation()
#15 /var/www/html/vendor/google/apiclient/src/AccessToken/Verify.php(105): Google\\AccessToken\\Verify->getFederatedSignOnCerts()
#16 /var/www/html/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Client.php(815): Google\\AccessToken\\Verify->verifyIdToken()
#17 /var/www/html/siohub/public/web/login.php(62): Google\\Client->verifyIdToken()
#18 {main}

Next GuzzleHttp\\Exception\\RequestException: Unable to read from stream in /var/www/html/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php:52
Stack trace:
#10 /var/www/html/vendor/google/apiclient/src/AccessToken/Verify.php(173): GuzzleHttp\\Client->get()
#11 /var/www/html/vendor/google/apiclient/src/AccessToken/Verify.php(201): Google\\AccessToken\\Verify->retrieveCertsFromLocation()
#12 /var/www/html/vendor/google/apiclient/src/AccessToken/Verify.php(105): Google\\AccessToken\\Verify->getFederatedSignOnCerts()
#13 /var/www/html/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Client.php(815): Google\\AccessToken\\Verify->verifyIdToken()
#14 /var/www/html/siohub/public/web/login.php(62): Google\\Client->verifyIdToken()
#15 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php on line 52, referer: http://localhost:8081/siohub/public/web/login.html
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for this and posting here for reference.

Google-Client uses GuzzleHttp to make api calls. In certain circumstances GuzzleHttp makes asynch calls (see trace snippet below). To handle this the Guzzle-Client needs to be configured with `['stream' => true]` and then assign the Guzzle-Client to the Google-Client as per the following.

```
$google = new Google\Client();
$guzzle = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['stream' => true]);
$google->setHttpClient($guzzle);
```

```
#11 /var/www/html/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php(187): GuzzleHttp\\Client->requestAsync()
#12 /var/www/html/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/ClientTrait.php(44): GuzzleHttp\\Client->request()
#13 /var/www/html/vendor/google/apiclient/src/AccessToken/Verify.php(173): GuzzleHttp\\Client->get()
#14 /var/www/html/vendor/google/apiclient/src/AccessToken/Verify.php(201): Google\\AccessToken\\Verify->retrieveCertsFromLocation()
```

In the [Guzzle Documentation](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/overview.html) there seems to be an explanation why guzzle switches to async mode. It says Guzzle will use the PHP stream wrapper to send HTTP requests if cURL is not installed.